# How to schedule regular executions dynamically?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I need to run some calculations periodically on a website. The difficult bit is that they don't run at fully regular intervals, as they are scheduled by the end users to run every N minutes (can be changed at any time), then would pause towards the end of the business day, and resume again the next morning, or else after a weekend. The end users can even specify days where it would not run at all. Basically I cannot use a fixed schedule.

Additionally, I have several of these calculations running concurrently with their own schedule.

So far I've been running this as a webjob, spinning multiple `Task` (one per calculation schedule), and awaiting (indefinitely) for all of them: `await Task.WhenAll(calculationTasks);`

Each task is made of a `while (true) {` loop, where I:

1. Run the actual calculation
2. Work out when should the next calculation be
3. Pause the thread `Thread.Sleep()` for the appropriate number of milliseconds: like I said above, this could be from a couple of minutes up to a few days.

It mostly works fine, however I've had instances where it would suddenly not work, and the webjob would require a restart. I'm lacking faith in this implementation as it somehow doesn't feel sturdy enough.

Has any of you ever run into a similar problem? What would be the best/approach implementation for this type of dynamic task scheduling?

Comment: Use something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) maybe? You could add every job separately and update it's schedule every time user does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like to Pawel's Hangfire suggestion with Functions. It's similar to what you are already doing. A web job acts a host behind the scenes and it runs the individual functions on the timers set in each function's [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer). You just won't have to do the messy work of keeping track of schedules or setting up the webjob.

You would run one function per job and use [C# script (.csx files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp) to keep the functions dynamic. The work comes in managing the function scripts.

Here's how I would convert your project. Feel free to borrow, edit, or make this your own way:

1. To make it easier to make updates I would take the logic of your calculations and make them into either a class library inside the `bin` folder or convert them to .csx files and add them to a `./shared` folder under your `wwwroot` folder. You'll then be able to make use of it in the functions without duplicating it by using `#load "..\shared\calculation1Logic.csx"`at the top of the function's .csx file. This is optional

So now we have: 
- wwwroot 
| - website (if you are using the same app service) 
| - shared 
 
| | - calculation1Logic.csx 
| | - calculation2Logic.csx

*or*

| bin 
| | calculationLogic.dll

---

2. Make some function templates that wrap each one of those calculations.

*calculation1Function.csx* example

```
#load "..\shared\calculation1Logic.csx"

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"running calculation 1: {DateTime.Now}");
    calculation1Logic(myTimer, log);
}
```

---

3. To create a new job, I would use the `createfunction` endpoint [in the Azure Management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createfunction) and pass it that template and a timer binding with the schedule converted to CRON syntax. Since this is much easier to create from an example, there's one in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4c91356-4de4-481c-83dc-7974f9ab1aae/creating-a-function-dynamically-using-azure-rest-api?forum=AzureFunctions) MSDN thread. It is in Node, but as I am using .csx instead of precompiled code the same method of dynamically adding functions will work. 
    Make sure to make the function names unique and store them so that you can edit or delete them later.

Now these are the files I have based on how this will get converted from the API request: 
- wwwroot 
| - website (if you are using the same app service) 
| - shared 
 
| | - calculation1Logic.csx 
| | - calculation2Logic.csx 
| - User1_Calculation1 
  | | - run.csx
  | | - function.json
  | | - function.proj
| - User2_Calculation2
  | | - run.csx
  | | - function.json
  | | - function.proj
| - host.json (part of the functions runtime along with extensions.csproj)
| - extensions.csproj
| - bin

---

4. Editing the schedule. This is where it gets a bit tricky. There are a couple ways to do this. The safest is to delete and re-add the function each time. The other is to replace the `function.json` with one with the updated binding. This way is a bit outside of what you 'should' do, but it allows for dynamic rebindings. `function.json` is a simple file if you just have the one binding, so you should be able to generate it progromaticaly.

*function.json* example

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can replace files in the App Service without a full deployment by accessing the files by FTP. Now, because changing the file via FTP [doesn't notify](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210) the host process that it has a new schedule to implement, you will need to send a request to `/syncfunctiontriggers` [via the management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/syncfunctiontriggers) to get it to update. This doesn't restart the full app, but if you are changing schedules often, you may want to have that API call run on a timer-- every minute or whatever interval works best for you.